# Show that $(\mathbf{x}, \boldsymbol\Theta\mathbf{x}+\boldsymbol\eta)$ is jointly normal

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, joint-distribution, multivariate-distribution

This is from Theodoridis' *Machine Learning*, exercise 3.16.

> Suppose $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector of jointly normal random variables
>   with covariance matrix $\boldsymbol\Sigma_x$. Let $$\mathbf{y} = \boldsymbol\Theta\mathbf{x}+\boldsymbol\eta$$ where
>   $\boldsymbol\Theta$ is a $k \times l$ matrix of [I assume, known or
>   fixed] parameters and $\boldsymbol\eta$ is normal with mean
>   $\mathbf{0}$ and covariance matrix $\boldsymbol\Sigma_\eta$,
>   independent of $\mathbf{x}$. Show that $\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{x}$
>   are jointly Gaussian with covariance matrix  $$\boldsymbol\Sigma =
>  \begin{bmatrix}
>  \boldsymbol\Theta\boldsymbol\Sigma_x\boldsymbol\Theta^{T}+\boldsymbol\Sigma_\eta
>  & \boldsymbol\Theta\boldsymbol\Sigma_x \\
>  \boldsymbol\Sigma_x\boldsymbol\Theta^{T} & \boldsymbol\Sigma_x
>  \end{bmatrix}\text{.}$$

It is clear that $\mathbf{y} \sim \mathcal{N}_k(\boldsymbol\Theta\boldsymbol\mu_x,\boldsymbol\Theta\boldsymbol\Sigma_x\boldsymbol\Theta^{T}+\boldsymbol\Sigma_\eta)$. This explains the top-left diagonal of $\boldsymbol\Sigma$.

The $\boldsymbol\Theta\boldsymbol\Sigma_x$, as well as the $\boldsymbol\Sigma_x\boldsymbol\Theta^{T}$, are easy to explain as well.

However, I'm not sure how to show that $\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ are **jointly** Gaussian. In particular, I considered looking at the distribution of $\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{x}$, but using this assumes bivariate normality of $(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})$ to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply an application of linear algebra to start working on with $x$ and $y$ jointly (no need to study the conditional distribution). Since we are interested in looking for the joint distribution of $[y', x']'$, it is natural by condition to express it as 
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
y \\
x
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\Theta x + \eta \\
x
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\Theta & I \\
I & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
\eta
\end{bmatrix}. \tag{1}
\end{align}

Since $x$ and $\eta$ are independent normal vectors respectively, it follows that
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
\eta
\end{bmatrix} \sim 
N\left(\begin{bmatrix}
\mu_x \\
0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma_x & 0 \\
0 & \Sigma_\eta
\end{bmatrix}\right).
\end{align}

Using the well-known [affine transformation property of normal random vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation), in view of $(1)$, $[y', x']'$ has multivariate normal distribution with the mean vector 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\Theta & I \\
I & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu_x \\
0
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\Theta \mu_x \\
\mu_x
\end{bmatrix}$$
and the covariance matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\Theta & I \\
I & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma_x & 0 \\
0 & \Sigma_\eta
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Theta & I \\
I & 0
\end{bmatrix}' = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\Theta\Sigma_x & \Sigma_\eta \\
\Sigma_x & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Theta' & I \\
I & 0
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\Theta\Sigma_x\Theta' + \Sigma_\eta & \Theta\Sigma_x \\
\Sigma_x\Theta' & \Sigma_x
\end{bmatrix}.$$
This completes the proof.

Comment: On one of my attempts to write down this problem, I wrote the equation $(1)$ but didn't know where to go from there... and this makes complete sense. Thanks!